# How to compute the Multifractal Spectrum of a Financial Series with WTMM

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics

I would like to know if someone knows how to compute the Multifractal Spectrum of a Financial Time Series (Currency) througth the Wavelet Transformation Modulus Maxima (WTMM).

I would highly appreciate any hint in order to calculate `Dq`, `Tau(q)`, `alpha`, `f(alpha)`.

I am pasting here the code I am using to get the Multifractal Spectrum 
(Ref: Gerd Baumann - Mathematica for Theoretical Physics (Mathematica 6.0), Springer Second Edition (2005),  page 892)
Comments: The following code helps to get the MultiFractal Spectrum, with *Mathematica* 6.0. 
I have updated the function `ListPlot` to `ListLinePlot` and `PlotJoined` to `Joined` as suggested in the Help of *Mathematica* 8.0.

The code seems to work when the input are the probabilities `pi ={p1,p2,....pn}` and when the values of each subset of the probability space one is seeking to characterize.

The code doesn't work 100% and I still don't know why (I am new to *Mathematica*).

The thing is, that the package provided by Mr. Baumann works when you give the input of the probabilities - yet I need that such process should be automated by the WTMM so I can see (analyze) the Whole Multifractal Spectrum.

----------------- ## ----------------------------

```
BeginPackage["MultiFractal`"];
Clear[Dq, Tau, Alpha, MultiFractal];
MultiFractal::usage = "MultiFractal[p_List,r_List] calculates the 
        multifractal spectrum D_q for a model based on the probabilities
        p and the scaling factors r. This function plots five functions
        Tau(q), D_q(q), Alpha(q), f(q) and f(Alpha).";
Begin["Private`"];

(*---calculate the multifractal dimensions---*)
Dq[p_List, r_List] := Block[{l1, l2, listrg = {}},
   (*---length of the lists---*)
   l1 = Length[p]; l2 = Length[r];
   If[l1 == l2,
    (*---variation of q and determination of D_q---*)
    Do[gl1 = Sum[p[[j]]^q r[[j]]^((q - 1) Dfractal), {j, 1, l1}] - 1;
     result = FindRoot[gl1 == 0, {Dfractal, -3, 3}];
     result = -Dfractal /. result;
     (*---collect the result in a list----*)
     AppendTo[listrg, {q, result}], {q, -10, 10, .101}]
    ,
    Print[" "];
    Print["  Lengths of lists are different!"];
    listrg = {}];
   listrg];

(*----calculate Tau---*)
Tau[result_list] := Block[{l1, listtau = {}},
   (*----lengths of the lists---*)
   l1 = Length[result];
   (*---calcultate Tau---*)
   Do[AppendTo[
     listtau, {result[[k, 1]], 
      result[[k, 2]] (1 - result[[k, 1]])}], {k, 1, l1}];
   listtau];

(*---Legendre transform---*)
Alpha[result_List] := 
  Block[{l1, dq, listalpha = {}, listf = {}, listleg = {}, mlist = {},
     pl1, pl2},
   (*---lengths of the lists---*)
   l1 = Length[result];
   (*---determine the differential dq---*)
   dq = (result[[2, 1]] - result[[1, 1]]) 2;
   (*---calculate Alpha by numerical differentiation---*)
   Do[AppendTo[
     listalpha, {result[[k, 
        1]], (result[[k + 1, 2]] - result[[k - 1, 2]])/dq}], {k, 2, 
     l1 - 1}];
   l1 = Length[listalpha];
   (*---calculate f and collect the result in a list---*)
   Do[AppendTo[
     listf, {result[[k, 
        1]], -(result[[k, 1]] listalpha[[k, 2]] - result[[k, 2]])}];
    listalpha[[k, 2]] = -listalpha[[k, 2]], {k, 1, 12}];
   (*---list of the Legendre transforms---*)
   Do[AppendTo[listleg, {listalpha[[k, 2]], listf[[k, 2]]}]; 
    AppendTo[mlist, listf[[k, 2]]], {k, 1, l2}];
   (*---plot f and alpha versus q---*)
   pl1 = ListLinePlot[listalpha, Joined -> {True, False}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"q", "\[Alpha]"}, Prolog -> Thickness[0.001]];
   pl2 = ListLinePlot[listf, Joined -> {True, False}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"q", "f"}, Prolog -> Thickness[0.001]];
   Show[{pl1, pl2}, AxesLabel -> {"q", "\[Alpha],f"}];
   (*---plot the Legendre transform f versus alpha---*)
   ListLinePlot[listleg, AxesLabel -> {"\[Alpha]", "f"}];
   (*---print the maximum of f=D_ 0---*)
   maxi = Max[mlist];
   Print[" "];
   Print["   D_0 = ", maxi]];

(*---calcultate the multifractal properties---*)
MultiFractal[p_List, r_List] := Block[{listDq, listTau},
   (*---determine D_q---*)
   listDq = Dq[p, r];
   ListLinePlot[listDq, Joined -> {True, False}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"q", "Dq"}, Prolog -> Thickness[0.001]]
     (*---calculate Tau---*)
      listTau = Tau[listDq];
   ListLinePlot[listTau, Joined -> {True, False}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"q", "\[Tau]"}, Prolog -> Thickness[0.001]]
    (*---determine the Hoelder exponent---*) 
    Alpha[listTau]];

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: Welcome to *Mathematica* SE! Your question (as it is) seems to be more suitable for the [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). If you want to know how to use Wolfram Mathematica to compute multifractal spectra please help us by adding a [minimal working code example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or anything that shows us your progress.

Comment: Thank you Jenson, I have added the code editing the initial comment (so to save space - hope it's ok with the Virtual Space Policies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code
(*Importation de la série*)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
d = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];
ima = Flatten[d];
ima = ima + 0.000001;
n1 = Length[d];
n2 = Log[2, Length[ima]];
ny = Table[2^i, {i, 3, n2}];

(*Calcul des valeurs Dq pour chaque sous série*)

f[n_] := Module[{xx = ima, d2, stot, freqpuis, somfreqpuis, pq},
  d2 = Partition[xx, n];
  fmaxmin[x_List] := Mean[x];
  stot = Map[fmaxmin, d2] // N;
  stot = stot/Total[Flatten[stot]];
  freqpuis = Table[stot^j, {j, -7, 7, 0.5}];
  somfreqpuis = Total[Transpose[freqpuis]];
  pq = Log[2, somfreqpuis]
  ]

logmuql = Flatten[Table[f[i], {i, ny}]] // N;
logmuqlt = Partition[logmuql, 29];
pqpart = logmuqlt;
logtaille = Log[2, ny] // N;

f2[nn_] := 
 Module[{a = logtaille, b = logmuqlt, essai, line, linen, fa1},
  essai = Partition[Riffle[logtaille, logmuqlt[[All, nn]]], 2];
  line = LinearModelFit[essai, x, x];
  linen = Normal[line];
  fa1 = linen[[2, 1]] // N
  ]

Dq = Table[f2[i], {i, 1, 29}];
qq = Table[i, {i, -7, 7, 0.5}];
q = 1/(qq - 1.000001);
Dqq = q*Dq;
kq = 2 - Dqq;
cq = kq*q;
qmoin = qq - 1;
rq = qmoin*Dq;
ecartDq = Dqq[[1]] - Dqq[[29]] // N;
Print["ecart Dq = ", ecartDq]
ListPlot[{pqpart[[All, 1]], pqpart[[All, 5]], pqpart[[All, 10]], 
   pqpart[[All, 15]], pqpart[[All, 20]], pqpart[[All, 29]]}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"log_tailleboite", "SomPiQ"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]

dqrel = Dqq - 1;
d3 = Riffle[qq, Dqq];
d6 = Partition[d3, 2];
d6 = Drop[d6, {17}];

ListPlot[{d6}, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"q", "Dq"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black}]

d3 = Riffle[qq, kq];
d6 = Partition[d3, 2];
d6 = Drop[d6, {17}];

ListPlot[{d6}, ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"q", "Kq"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black}]

d3 = Riffle[qq, cq];
d6 = Partition[d3, 2];
d6 = Drop[d6, {17}];
ListPlot[{d6}, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"q", "Cq"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black}]

d3 = Riffle[qmoin, rq];
d6 = Partition[d3, 2];
d6 = Drop[d6, {17}];
ListPlot[{d6}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"q", "Tauq"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black}]

d3 = Riffle[qq, dqrel];
d6 = Partition[d3, 2];
d6 = Drop[d6, {17}];
ListPlot[{d6}, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"q", "Dq_Relatif"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black}]

fo[n_] := 
  Module[{xx = ima, d2, stot, tfreqpuis, freqpuis, logfreqpuis, 
    produitfreq, somfproduit4},
  d2 = Partition[xx, n];
  fmaxmin[x_List] := Mean[x];
  stot = Map[fmaxmin, d2] // N;
  freqpuis = Table[stot^j, {j, -7, 7, 0.5}];
  tfreqpuis = Total[Transpose[freqpuis]];
  freqpuis = freqpuis/tfreqpuis;
  logfreqpuis = Log[10, freqpuis];
  produitfreq = freqpuis*logfreqpuis;
  somfproduit4 = Map[Total, produitfreq] // N
  ]

totlogmuql = Flatten[Table[fo[i], {i, ny}]];
logmuqlt = Partition[totlogmuql, 29];
pqpart = logmuqlt;
logtaille = Log[10, ny] // N;

fo2[nn_] := 
 Module[{a = logtaille, b = logmuqlt, essai, line, linen, fa1},
  essai = Partition[Riffle[logtaille, logmuqlt[[All, nn]]], 2];
  line = LinearModelFit[essai, x, x];
  linen = Normal[line];
  fa1 = ToExpression[linen[[2, 1]]] // N
  ]

fqr = Table[fo2[i], {i, 1, 29}];
qq = Table[i, {i, -7, 7, 0.5}];
fq2 = Riffle[qq, fqr];
fq2 = Partition[fq2, 2];

ListPlot[{fq2}, 
  ImageSize -> {300, 200}, Joined -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"q", "f(alpha)q"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black}]
ecartFq = fqr[[29]] - fqr[[1]] // N;
Print["ecart Fq = ", ecartFq]
```

Comment: Thank you @Dauphine so much bests!

Comment: Dear @Dauphine, I have run your code, yet I found a lot of 'errors' in my Mathematica 8.0 (could that be?), any idea what might be different?

Comment: These are some of the errors that I get:

Set::write: Tag Times in d Null is Protected. >>

Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[d]. >>

Partition::pdep: Depth 1 requested in object with dimensions {}. >>

ecart Dq = -0.291667 Dq

Part::partd: Part specification Partition[logmuql,29][[All,1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Part::partd: Part specification Partition[logmuql,29][[All,5]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Part::partd: Part specification Partition[logmuql,29][[All,10]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Comment: in f2[nn_] theres is a ";" missing in the line "fa1 = linen[[2, 1]] // N ] Dq = Table[f2[i], {i, 1, 29}];" --> or it is ok without ";"? - I highly appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you so much for correcting the code. Now it works. Thank you very very much!