# Help with debugging my code

Tags: plotting, fractals, broken-code

In order to descrive the multifractal behaviour of a set, Baumann provides a code based on the functions Dq and Tau, given below.

```
       Dq[p_List, r_List] := 
       Block[{l1, l2, listrg = {}},(*----length of the lists---*)
       l1 = Length[p];
       l2 = Length[r];
       If[l1 == l2,(*----variation of q and determination of D_q---*)
       Do[gl1 = Sum[p[[j]]^q r[[j]]^((q - 1) Dfractal), {j, 1, l1}] - 1;
       result = FindRoot[gl1 == 0, {Dfractal, -3, 3}];
       result = -Dfractal /. result;
       (*----collect the results in a list---*)
       AppendTo[listrg, {q, result}], {q, -10, 10, .101}], Print[" "];
       Print[" Lengths of lists are different!"];
       listrg = {}];
       listrg]

       (*----calculate Tau---*)
       Tau[result_list] := 
       Block[{l1, listtau = {}},(*----lengths of the lists---*)
       l1 = Length[result];
       (*---calcultate Tau---*)
       Do[AppendTo[
       listtau, {result[[k, 1]], 
       result[[k, 2]] (1 - result[[k, 1]])}], {k, 1, l1}];
       listtau];


       p = {2/5, 2/5, 1/5};
       r = {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};
       ListDq = Dq[p, r];
       ListLinePlot[ListDq, AxesLabel -> {"q", "Dq"}]
       listTau = Tau[listDq];
       ListLinePlot[listTau, Joined -> {True, False}, 
       AxesLabel -> {"q", "\[Tau]"}, Prolog -> Thickness[0.001]]
```

The code above provides the plot of Dq but gives problems on Tau. In particular, the following errors are given:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `list` -> `List`?

Comment: As I undestood, I should try with                                                                                                         **Tau[result_List] := in**   instead of  **Tau[result_list] :=**. Can it work?

Comment: It does not work. Any other idea?

Comment: "I does not work" - is meaningless. Please update the question with correct code, test example and explanation why it does not fit your expectations.

Comment: I want to say that the package gives me the following error: "ListLinePlot: Private`listTau is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers'." It seems that there is an error in listTau. If you want to see the whole code, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188070/multifractal-package-description-of-multifractals?noredirect=1#comment490483_188070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple mistakes.

`Tau[result_list] :=` should be `Tau[result_List] :=`

and

`listTau = Tau[listDq];` should be `listTau = Tau[ListDq];`

Mathematica is case-sensitive. You must be careful about capitalization in identifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It finally works!!!

Comment: @Spook82. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: Is it correct? You solved a big problem!

Comment: @Spook82. Yes, your acceptance has been registered.